# Data representation, MindMap creation, Cross-Platform Library

Tags: library, cross-platform, data-visualization, mind-mapping

I am looking for a cross-platform library that would help me to draw/represent data but most of all should help me to **visualize mind maps**; something similar like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) but with language bindings so that it can be cross-platform compiled.

The reason is that I don't want to write my own "engine" to be able to render just a mind map. Is there something that could help me here?

Comment: How about a JavaScript framework that can extend the D3 library? Also, are you drawing mind maps for personal use or is this feeding into an app's development?

Comment: It is supposed to be a part of a desktop application. I am not really a big fan of JavaScript and the d3.js library is not very fast for what I could observe. I am not up-to-date but maybe this could have changed already since the possibility of web-workers.

Comment: Did you get anywhere? I have starred this question as I am interested in the answer. If you made a decision, could you please tell us what and why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/)?

Your question is a little sketchy, but I think that it will help.

It is text driven, so can be used to represent data.

As an example:

```
graph { 
    a -- b; 
    b -- c; 
    a -- c; 
    d -- c; 
    e -- c; 
    e -- a; 
}
```

generates
[image]

Please take a look at [the gallery](http://graphviz.org/Gallery.php) more more complex (mindmapish) examples..

[This question](http://www.graphviz.org/content/mindmap-layout) on their forum addresses creating mindmaps.

See also [Graphviz+Jessyink as a Latex-Style Potential Alternative to Prezi and Mindmap Presentations (How to Beat MS PowerPoint)](http://blog.ofset.org/ckhung/index.php?post/118a).

[This Ruby tool](https://github.com/joshsz/ruby-graphviz-mindmap) might also help.

Comment: Do you know of a web alternative to Graphviz? In the sense..you give it the same input and it outputs a html page with graphs?

Comment: Alas, no. I have no personal use for such, but if you do find one I would ask you to post it here in order to benefit others in the future. Good luck!